# Clang vs. GCC when static_cast'ing to a move-only type

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider the following simple move-only class:

```
struct bar {
    constexpr bar() = default;
    bar(bar const&) = delete;
    bar(bar&&)      = default;
    bar& operator=(bar const&) = delete;
    bar& operator=(bar&&)      = default;
};
```

Now, let's create a wrapper:

```
template <class T>
struct box {
    constexpr box(T&& x)
        : _payload{std::move(x)}
    {}

    constexpr explicit operator T() &&
    {
        return std::move(_payload);
    }

  private:
    T _payload;
};
```

And a test:

```
int main()
{
    auto x = box<bar>{bar{}};
    auto y = static_cast<bar&&>(std::move(x));
}
```

Clang-6.0 is happy with this code if compiled with `-std=c++14` or above. GCC-8.1 however produces the following error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:29:45: error: invalid static_cast from type 'std::remove_reference<box<bar>&>::type' {aka 'box<bar>'} to type 'bar&&'
     auto y = static_cast<bar&&>(std::move(x));
```

Here's a [link to compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/CU19f2) to try it out.

So my question is, who's right and who's wrong?

Comment: g++ compiles if you change `operator T()` to `operator T&&()`

Comment: simplified: https://godbolt.org/g/6Gpmb8

Comment: Also compiles if you remove the `explicit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplified example:

```
struct bar 
{
    bar() = default;
    bar(bar const&) = delete;
    bar(bar&&) = default;
};

struct box 
{
    explicit operator bar() && { return bar{}; }
};

int main() { static_cast<bar&&>(box{}); }
```

[**live on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/DB5hFk)

---

First of all, let's see what it means for a conversion operator to be `explicit`:

> A conversion function may be explicit, in which case it is only considered as a user-defined conversion for **direct-initialization**. Otherwise, user-defined conversions are not restricted to use in assignments and initializations.

Is `static_cast` considered **direct-initialization**?

> The initialization that occurs in the forms
>
> ```
> T x(a);
> T x{a};
> ```
>
> as well as in new expressions, **static_­cast** expressions, functional notation type conversions, mem-initializers, and the braced-init-list form of a condition is called **direct-initialization**.

---

Since `static_cast` is *direct-initalization*, it doesn't matter whether the conversion operator is marked `explicit` or not. However, removing `explicit` makes the code compile on both *g++* and *clang++*: [**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/hQm3B8).

This makes me believe that it's a *g++* bug, as `explicit` makes a difference here... when it shouldn't.